# Driver install necessary on ThinkPad with two GPUs?

Tags: xorg, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I'm not that new to Linux but just used it the last years for server and/or testing most often in VMs. Now I've just got a new ThinkPad and I want to use Debian as a native install.

My notebook:
Lenovo ThinkPad t460p with a
NVidia GeForce 940MX
([German Shop Site](http://www.campuspoint.de/20fxs05500-lenovocampus-thinkpad-t460p.html#tabs) for additional details).

But now I'm wondering which additional steps I have to do since my notebook has two GPU (Intel + Nvidia). I had installed the Nvidia-driver package via the Debian backport source (not sure if this was correct) like described in the Debian manual.

When doing a `lsmod | grep nvidia` the Nvidia entry will be listed (as far I understand that means, that the Nvidia driver is loaded and nouveau should not). I'm trusting the original Nvidia driver in general more than the nouveau because I want to be sure that my card is optimal used; also I've heard about nouveau today the first time). Anyway their are some Points I'm wondering about:

`#lspci | grep VGA` returns only a Intel entry:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 191b (rev 06)`

`#nvidia-detect` returns `No NVIDIA GPU detected.`

`#lspci | grep NVIDIA` returns `02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 134d (rev a2)`

As in many tutorials described, I should install the Nvidia-xconfig package to be able to run `nvidia-config` for creating a xorg-config-file.

Maybe I don't have to do anything and that is all right? It's correct that my system should only use the intel-adapter per default. Just when running some intensive OpenGL-Applications, the Nvidia should be used (at least that is the behaviour I'm used to from the windows-world).

One more idea is, that I have to use that bumblebee-driver I've just found...?

Hope you can help me with this noobish-problems so I can switch away
from windows. :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Short version, you have 3 options:

1- Remove the Nvidia drivers and use only the Intel graphics.

2- Remove the Intel drivers (is that still necessary?) and use only the Nvidia graphics.

3- Use both by getting Bumblebee/Primus/("Optimus" in the Windows world) working.

Don't remember where exactly, but there was a good guide on the Arch wiki somewhere. I think I was searching for "nvidia optimus linux".